# Django Dynamic Form Choices from ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to build a form that displays dynamic choices

How do I build a Form where the athlete's Sport is a choicefield populated with sports related to the Event that the athlete is participating in...

my models are as follows...

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class EventCode(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    Sports = models.ManyToManyField(Sport)

class Athlete(models.Model):
    Event = models.ForeignKey(EventCode)
    Sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you know the event code when you are building the form 
This is the way you filter on the `EventCode`:

```
sport_choices = EventCode.objects.filter(pk=event).values_list('Sports','Sports__Type')
```

lets say the event is jump then you will get [(5,'long jump'),(7,'frog jump')....]

Now the way you set the related choices is

```
Class AthleteForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Athlete
      def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
          super(AthleteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          event = kwargs['event']
          self.fields['Event'].initial = event
          self.fields['Sport'].choices =  EventCode.objects.filter(pk=event).values_list('Sports','Sports__Type')
```

If you want to do this when you select an `event` in the form then you can pass the `event` as `ajax request` generate the `sport_choices` for the selected event and return it as a response to the ajax request.

Comment: so in my view is this the right way to call it?
`form = AthleteForm(request.POST or None, event = id)`

Comment: yes you can pass the `event = id` and extract it from `kwargs` in the `__init__` method. Just add `event != None` only then set the initial and the choices, just to avoid sql errors.